# White highlight around text when setting background color

Tags: python, tkinter

When I set the background color, there's a white highlight around the text. How do I fix this? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvGb9.png) Thank you.

```
entry_text = Label(newWindow, wraplength=350, justify=LEFT, text="test").pack()
```

Comment: Try putting `bg="grey"` in the label's constructor.

Comment: When you say _"When I set the background color"_, how are you doing that? The example you show doesn't set the background color.

Comment: tkinter `Label` does not support transparent background.